# SQL to count the instance and total instances on sorted data

Tags: sql

Is there an efficient way to add the Instance and Instances columns on sorted SQL? Some kind of self join? I quite often have to do something like this and loop through the data, having to allow for row 1 being a special case, backfilling the total instances with a reverse loop, but I suspect there may be a simpler way.

[image: Example result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic analytic functions would appear what you need:

```
Select field,
  row_number() over(partition by field order by <some ordering column> ) Instance,
  count(*) over(partition by field) Instances
from YourTable;
```